# Is it possible to interact with your computer through Lua?

Tags: lua, interactive

I was wondering if it is possible to interact with your computer through Lua (Through SciTE or Sublime Text, I suppose...)? For instance, can you play a `.mp3`, or open a file with Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through the use of the operating system library `os`.

You can use `os.execute([command])` to run any command from the host operating system's shell (think terminal or command prompt).

There's more information on using this library in the [Lua online reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.8).

Comment: Didn't know anything in the os library had the ability of doing this, thanks!